# Unable to install Ruby OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, centos7

So, I just updated Ruby version on a CentOS 7 box, to allow for the use of OpenSSL, using this guide:
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=ruby23

However, the version is now set to 2.3.8 as per:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.8p459 (2018-10-18 revision 65136) [x86_64-linux]
```

and:

```
$ which ruby
/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/ruby
$ which gem
/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/gem
```

BUT, gem throws the same error as before hand:

```
$ sudo gem install openssl
ERROR:  Error installing openssl:
        openssl requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` when installing gems? Probably `su` env uses some older ruby version. Try without it...

Comment: You can test by `sudo ruby -v`

Comment: I did consult with a colleague, and he suggested the same idea... However, I could still not use gem to install openSSL, it simply gave me the same error message. 

I tried gem update, then tried again... I'm thinking it might be a gem versioning issue... Will try that line of reasoning and get back to you on that one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gems without `sudo`. I did such test locally

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux] 
$ sudo ruby -v
sudo: ruby: command not found
```

Probably your superuser env is not using the same ruby version as your current user's env.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input.. I spoken to a colleague, who did suggest the same thing... However, I tried to install the same version as both super user and normal user, and still had the same problem :/

Comment: But why do you install gems with `sudo`, is there a special need for that?

Comment: I simply tried sudo as doing it as the current user didn't work.... I was under the impression that sudo might have fixed it... To no avail :/